# Is there any way to group by continious values

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have data from car gps tracker and I need to find parking and movement periods

Now every row have id of parking or movement in table

```
+------------+-------+----------+---------+------------+
|    time    | speed | ignition | trip_id | parking_id |
+------------+-------+----------+---------+------------+
| 05:48:50   |     0 | false    |       0 |        300 |
| 05:49:20   |     0 | false    |       0 |        300 |
| 05:49:20   |    10 | true     |     300 |          0 |
| 05:50:01   |    20 | true     |     300 |          0 |
| 05:51:20   |    17 | true     |     300 |          0 |
| 05:51:20   |     0 | false    |       0 |        301 |
| 05:52:40   |     0 | false    |       0 |        301 |
| 05:52:40   |    12 | true     |     301 |          0 |
| 05:52:50   |    22 | true     |     301 |          0 |
| 05:53:00   |    30 | true     |     301 |          0 |
| 05:53:30   |    40 | true     |     301 |          0 |
| 05:53:30   |     0 | false    |       0 |        302 |
| 05:55:00   |     0 | false    |       0 |        302 |
+------------+-------+----------+---------+------------+
```

```sql
SELECT min(time) as time_start, max(time) as time_end, trip_id, parking_id
FROM 'tablename' GROUP BY trip_id, parking_id
```

result is

```
+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| time start | time end | trip id | parking id |
+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| 05:48:50   | 05:49:20 |       0 |         300|
| 05:49:20   | 05:51:20 |      300|          0 |
| 05:51:20   | 05:52:40 |       0 |         301|
| 05:52:40   | 05:53:30 |      301|          0 |
| 05:53:30   | 05:55:00 |       0 |         302|
+------------+----------+---------+------------+
```

How should I do group by so as not to use parking_id and trip_id. But generate parking ids and trip ids. And the final result must be:

```
+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| time start | time end | trip id | parking id |
+------------+----------+---------+------------+
| 05:48:50   | 05:49:20 |       0 |          1 |
| 05:49:20   | 05:51:20 |       1 |          0 |
| 05:51:20   | 05:52:40 |       0 |          2 |
| 05:52:40   | 05:53:30 |       2 |          0 |
| 05:53:30   | 05:55:00 |       0 |          3 |
+------------+----------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: the same as it was originally, but the request should not use parking_id and trip_id

Comment: Please include the output you actually _do_ want to see.

Comment: How would you get the values from trip_id and parking_id without using them?

Comment: Speaking: It is no problem to create groups only using ignition (and speed, because of your tied timestamps). In the end you would be able to do group by my_new_group_id. But then you'll need to name a trip_id. Either in the grouping clause or within the aggregations function. Otherwise you cannot show them... It's not clear what you mean with "without trip_id".

Comment: I have to correct: Your timestamps are not precise enough to do this: You have twice "05:49:29" with increasing speed, but "05:53:30" with decreasing speed. So, it is not clear in which order these data sets should be handled. You have to use milliseconds as well!

Comment: I edited the final result